# Old style figures in math with newpxmath

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

I am using the packages `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` (both from `newpx`) with the option `\useosf` to get old style figures together with Palatino. However, I have searched in vain for a way of getting old style figures in math as well as in text. This option is offered for example by the MinionPro package, but I have not been able to find a similar functionality for Palatino

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\useosf
\begin{document}
    Hello world, 2017.
    \begin{equation}
        V = \frac{4\pi}{3}r^3
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newtxtext redefines `\rmdefault` only at the begin of the document and this too late to affect math. You can reset the operator font like this, but imho the old style numbers looks odd in math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\useosf
\AtEndPreamble{\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}}
\begin{document}
    Hello world, 2017.
    \begin{equation}
        V = \frac{2107\pi}{3}r^3
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I kind of agree with you on the osf in display math, BUT since without this fix inline math is set with lining numbers, you get a weird mix of old style and lining numbers. Also, while it may look weird in some cases, I also think that limiting the use of figures to one kind has merit. Sometimes you cant have everything. 

Your solution completely solves the technical side of my problem - now it's just a matter of choosing.